# Facebook Messengerbot python ( The Callback URL or Verify Token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.)

Tags: python, django, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Am trying to implement facebook messenger chatbot in python. Am created One API in python below

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def verify(request):
    form_data = request.query_params
    mode = form_data.get('hub.mode')
    token = form_data.get('hub.verify_token')
    challenge = form_data.get('hub.challenge')
    if mode and token:
        if mode == 'subscribe' and token == "mytestingtoken":
            print("WEBHOOK_VERIFIED")
            return JsonResponse({"code":200,'message':challenge})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"code":403})
    return JsonResponse({"code":200,'message':'test'})
```

am mapping the API URL into ngrok URL(https://55d71a8248be.ngrok.io)

then am created a Facebook App and configured a webhook.
here callback URL and Verify Token also setup.
but finally I got Error Message

`The Callback URL or Verify Token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.`[image]

Am referred facebook document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup

Comment: I'm all the sudden getting this error. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HttpResponse for API Response
return HttpResponse("message",200)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll need setup auth token for ngrok.

[image]